# How to remove password prompt when executing su <user> command in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

I have two users in my CentOS system User1 and User2. I am logged in as root user and trying to add User1 to sudoer list using `visudo`. I have entered the following line at the end of the file

`User1  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

But, when I log in as User1 the `su User2` command gives me a password prompt. I do not want to provide password and instead User1 should be able to switch to User2 without any password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/etc/sudoers` config file doesn't configure the `su` command, which will always prompt for credentials in accordance with whatever's in `/etc/pam.d/su`. The command you're looking for is `sudo -iu User2`